# Accessing objects inside a custom ListAdpater events clicks

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I have this implementation of ListAdapter:

```
public class TaskAdapter implements ListAdapter, View.OnClickListener {

Context                 context;

List<Task>              tasks;

// View adapterView;
public TaskAdapter(Context context, List<Task> tasks) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.tasks = tasks;
} ...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    Task data = tasks.get(position);
    Button task_menu_bt = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.taskMenuButton);

        task_menu_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                **//     How to access current Task data??  i can not do tasks.get(position)**
            }
        });
```

}

My question is how can i access Task data from inside the onClick event on a button located in the item row (not the view click but a button on the list view)?

My task class contains for exmaple getName() methods and others...

Comment: You should look into [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

Comment: why cant you use `task.get(position)` there?

Comment: @tyczj "Cannot refer to a non-final variable data inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: so make position `final` or make data `final` though i think getting the task on the position is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using onClickListener's implement as an inner class, the variable won't be accessable inside it. 
So you should either declare a Task variable at Adapter level, basically a member of TaskAdapter or make it final either if it will work

```
    public class TaskAdapter implements ListAdapter, View.OnClickListener {

Context                 context;

List<Task>              tasks;
Task data;

// View adapterView;
public TaskAdapter(Context context, List<Task> tasks) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.tasks = tasks;
} ...



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    data = tasks.get(position);
    Button task_menu_bt = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.taskMenuButton);

        task_menu_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                **//     How to access current Task data??  i can not do tasks.get(position)**
            }
        });

final Task data = tasks.get(position);
```

One of the better way to access an item is to override the [getItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29) method and return the object from the data source there.

```
public Object getItem (int position){
    return (Task)tasks.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the data by changing your instantiation of Task to

```
final Task data = tasks.get(position);
```